# Mysql doesn't return the correct id of the inserted row

Tags: mysql

I use [Mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) in a project. That Mysqljs libray has a feature to get the id of an inserted row.

> If you are inserting a row into a table with an auto increment primary
>   key, you can retrieve the insert id like this:
>
> connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function
>   (error, results, fields) {   if (error) throw error;
>   console.log(results.insertId); });

**But the wired thing in here is**, it doesn't return the correct inserted id.

I imported my database from a script (without data only structure) but it still takes the old inserted ids I guess.

I have a table called `item`
first time I inserted, it returns the **insertId as 143** even through I can see the id field for my first record is inserted to table as 1.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Removing currently inserted rows does not reset auto increment value. Please `truncate` table and repeat insertion.

Comment: *" it returns the insertId as 143 even through I can see the id field for my first record is inserted to table as 1."* i don't believe that pretty sure the inserted record does not have id 1 when insertId  (node.js) says 143...

Answer (score 0):

There's no error in your code and in your table too, if you have already written tuples and next, deleted in that table, the answer is here.

**How does it work really autoincrement ID into MySQL databases**

To guarantee unicity over autoincrement columns, the DBMS store the status of the column itself as "counter".

Starting from the real beginnings: let's suppose that we have a table called "people": id as primary key not null autoincrement, name and surname.

**It has been never populated before.**

I do an insert, like:

```
insert into people(name, surname) values ('Mickey','Mouse')
```

It'll have as "id" value "1".

Let's assume that, after this operation, I'll insert more 99 different records: the 100th will have "100" as "id" value.

**Then, let's delete all the 100 tuples we've inserted before into the table.**

Right now, if I execute one more time:

```
insert into people(name, surname) values ('Mickey','Mouse')
```

I'll see that, the new record has "101" as "id" value.

**In a nutshell: to maintain integrity over autoincrement columns, the DBMS will keep track of deleted records and *this doesn't mean that it'll be reseted too*.**

Indeed, it won't.